# Tomcat7 rewrites my context.xml when extracting war file

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot

My java application has more versions of external context.xml, one for each environment. The plan is to have one war file and using the right context.xml for production, staging, dev, etc.

I currently copy/symlink the context.xml into `/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.72/conf/Catalina/localhost/myapp.xml`. Then I create war file from my sources and I copy it into `/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.72/webapps`. The catalina is running and explodes the war file in webapps folder. In the same time it deletes my `myapp.xml` from conf folder. For that reason my app doesn't load the proper configuration and fails. If I copy again the myapp.xml and restart tomcat it works.

Is there a way to tell tomcat to not delete my conf file when extracting war file? Or is there a better place for external context.xml

Comment: Why? Tomcat will copy the one in META-INF/context.xml in your WAR file. You don't need to do any manual copying yourself.

Comment: @EJP context.xml is not part of code repository. Developer has his own credentials for testing purposes and doesn't know live DB credentials. Once war file is uploaded to artifactory, it can be used on different environments using the correct context.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have some params in this context.xml for production or stage etc. It's not a good idea to store them there as better approach is to start server with properties and read them in webapp so you never make mistake a.

Look here: https://eureka.ykyuen.info/2009/12/15/tomcat-setting-java-system-properties-for-webapps/